# Nodetool rebuild not working reliably on Cassandra 3.11.3

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I presently have a cassandra 3.11.3 cluster with a single DC. I recently added another dc to my cluster. And I followed the instructions @
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html

As per the instructions I ran 'nodetool rebuild -ks  -- dc1 on each of the nodes. However this rebuild command did not actually work as intended. My data is partially missing in the new nodes. This I know because  I sampled the data in the new dc through my app using consistency local_one. I dont see the data replenish through read repair either. Oh and I should mention that there were no errors in the logs following the rebuild command. So everything appeared to have succeeded.

What am I missing here? Is there a known issue reported on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should run `nodetool rebuild --<existing DC>` on each node. this command will pull all keyspace data from existing data center based on allocated tokens and RF. To ensure consistency please run full repair on nodes as well.